Python : filter set/list of tuple based on cardinality property
I'm looking for a way to filter a set (or list) of tuples based on the number of times an
item appears in one of the other of the position of the tuple.
My current goal is a bit complex so I divided the problem in three smaller steps.
1. Let's start with the simplest case, only a single value which applies only to the first element of the tuple
For instance:
my_filter([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,4),(3,5),(5,2),(5,4)], 2)

Should return:
[(1,2),(1,3),(5,2),(5,4)]

Because these are the only tuples for which the first item of the tuple is linked appears only twice in the whole list.
The naive way of doing it is : for each first element of tuple in list, count the number of times this element appears as first element in all tuples and, if the count matches the chosen number, add all tuples having this element at first position.
But I feel like this is so unoptimal and I have to iterate over the list for each possible value, I'm surely missing a better way of doing it.
2. Make it reciprocal
Ideally it would like to be able to apply the same treatment based on the second element of the tuple, with another cardinality parameter
For instance:
my_filter([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,4),(3,5),(5,2),(5,4)], 2, 1)

Here we want to keep only tuples in which the first element appears exactly twice but with the second element appearing only once (intersection of the two conditions). This should return:
[(1,3)]

3. Generalizing to multiple values
my_filter([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,4),(3,5),(5,2),(5,4)], 2, [1,3])

In this case, we allow the cardinality filter to take multiple possible values. In this example, we want to keep tuples for which the first element appears exactly twice (in first position) and the second element appears either once or three times (in the second position). This should return:
[(1,3),(5,4)]

Once again, I have no problem writing a naive solution that would simply iterate over each allowed values and join result sets, but I'm looking for something smarter.
I feel like there could be some useful functions in the itertools library but I'm not comfortable enough with it. Any advice ? Thanks.

Here's a linear time (O(n)) solution for parts 2 and 3 (1 can be implemented with some tweaks):
First we convert the second and third arguments into a set, which is O(n).
Then we calculate the frequency of each element at position 0 and 1, again O(n).
Then we iterate over the list and check whether it matches our criteria. Lookups in Counter and sets are both O(1) so this thing is again efficient, O(n) overall.
from collections import Counter


def my_filter(list: list[tuple[int, int]], first: list[int], second: list[int]):
    first_set = set(first)
    second_set = set(second)
    first_counter = Counter(a for (a, _) in list)
    second_counter = Counter(b for (_, b) in list)
    return [
        (a, b)
        for (a, b) in list
        if first_counter[a] in first_set and second_counter[b] in second_set
    ]


print(
    my_filter(
        [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (5, 2), (5, 4)], [2], [1]
    )
)

print(
    my_filter(
        [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (5, 2), (5, 4)], [2], [1, 3]
    )
)

Output:
[(1, 3)]
[(1, 3), (5, 4)]


Perfect thank you ! It works fine. Counter is what i was missing. The first case can obviously easily be solved since it is a specific case.

This can be made significantly faster by not using Counter and iterating over list  just once to produce first_counter and second_counter

Since itertools' Counter is written in C and highly optimized I doubt that vanilla python can outperform its usage, even though we need to iterate over the list twice with Counter

@ibi0tuxI have added another answer as proof of my assertion

A performance improvement over the otherwise excellent proposition by @Dogbert
from collections import Counter
from timeit import timeit

# code from the accepted answer
def my_filter1(list: list[tuple[int, int]], first: list[int], second: list[int]):
    first_set = set(first)
    second_set = set(second)
    first_counter = Counter(a for (a, _) in list)
    second_counter = Counter(b for (_, b) in list)
    return [
        (a, b)
        for (a, b) in list
        if first_counter[a] in first_set and second_counter[b] in second_set
    ]

# code that avoids use of Counter
def my_filter2(list: list[tuple[int, int]], first: list[int], second: list[int]):
    first_set = set(first)
    second_set = set(second)
    first_counter = {}
    second_counter = {}
    for a, b in list:
        first_counter[a] = first_counter.get(a, 0) + 1
        second_counter[b] = second_counter.get(b, 0) + 1
    return [
        (a, b)
        for (a, b) in list
        if first_counter[a] in first_set and second_counter[b] in second_set
    ]


X = [(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (5, 2), (5, 4),(1,2)]
Y = [2]
Z = [1]

assert my_filter1(X, Y, Z) == my_filter2(X, Y, Z)

for func in my_filter1, my_filter2:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(X,Y,Z)))

Output:
my_filter1 2.4996074590017088
my_filter2 1.1667742919817101

Platform:
Apple M2
macOS Sonoma 14.6
Python 3.12.4


Great performance improvment thank you!
